# Multi dictionaries - For all identical keys, do some aggregation

Tags: python, for-loop, file-io, dictionary

The following is the output of 1 python script:

```
 { 12: {'@': False, '#': False, 'word': 'good#1st#time#will',    'longword': True, 'title': False, 'charcount': 18, 'uppercase': False, 'stop': False, 'sscore': False, 'url': False, '!!!': False} }
 { 12: {'@': False, '#': False, 'word': 'be', 'longword': False, 'title': False,   'charcount': 2, 'uppercase': False, 'stop': True, 'sscore': False, 'url': False, '!!!': False} }
 { 12: {'@': False, '#': False, 'word': 'going', 'longword': False, 'title': False, 'charcount': 5, 'uppercase': False, 'stop': False, 'sscore': False, 'url': False, '!!!': False} }
 { 13: {'@': False, '#': False, 'word': 'back#', 'longword': False, 'title': False, 'charcount': 5, 'uppercase': False, 'stop': False, 'sscore': False, 'url': False, '!!!': False} }
 { 13: {'@': False, '#': False, 'word': 'http://instagr.am/p/rx9939civ8/\xc2\xa0', 'longword': True, 'title': False, 'charcount': 33, 'uppercase': False, 'stop': False, 'sscore': False, 'url': True, '!!!': False} }
```

In another python script, the above is taken as a input. All the above code is different dictionaries being the output of 1 script but in another script, I want to do a sum of 'charcount' or count number of longword=True where these multi-dictionaries have identical keys so the output would look like:

```
 { 12: {'longword': 1 ,'charcount': 25} }
 { 13: {'longword': 1 ,'charcount': 38} }
```

My dataset does not group them but outputs single dictionaries with 12 as key and 13 as key. My code should be able to find all the identical keys as I have a big dataset and do the above aggregation

Here is my code which takes the above as multi-dictionary but I do not understand how I would do aggregation.

```
 dicts = {}
 for line in sys.stdin:
    d = ast.literal_eval(line)
    for k,v in d.items():
       dicts.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
       for key,val in v.items():
```

This is the code I have so far.

Comment: Are the outer dictionaries sorted? In other words, does your dataset group all `12` lines, then all `13` lines, etc.?

Comment: I also have to sort the dictionary by keys. My dataset does not group them but outputs single dictionaries with 12 as key and 13 as key. 
My code should be able to find all the identical keys as I have a big dataset and do the above aggregation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to iterate `v`, because keys you're interested in are fixed.

```
import ast
import sys

dicts = {}
for line in sys.stdin:
    d = ast.literal_eval(line)
    for k, v in d.items():
        inner_dict = dicts.setdefault(k, {})
        inner_dict['longword'] = inner_dict.get('longword', 0) + v.get('longword', 0)
        inner_dict['charcount'] = inner_dict.get('charcount', 0) + v.get('charcount', 0)

print dicts
```

`dicts` become:

```
{12: {'charcount': 25, 'longword': 1},
 13: {'charcount': 38, 'longword': 1}}
```

Comment: how is it finding identical keys?

Comment: @kulkarni.ankita09, Explicitly specified in the code: `inner_dict('longword', 0)`, `v.get('longword', 0)`.

Comment: it just gives {'charcount': 25, 'longword': 1}
{'charcount': 38, 'longword': 1} as output and not with the key. See the code I edited.

Comment: @kulkarni.ankita09, `print dicts` after the `for` loop gives `{12: {'charcount': 25, 'longword': 1}, 13: {'charcount': 38, 'longword': 1}}` as output.

Answer (score 1):

Using `collections.default`:

```
import sys
import ast
from collections import defaultdict
my_dict = defaultdict(lambda: {'longword':0, 'charcount':0})
for line in sys.stdin:
    d = ast.literal_eval(line)
    key = list(d)[0]
    my_dict[key] = {k: d[key][k]+v for k, v in my_dict[key].items()}
print my_dict
```

**Output:**

```
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0xb7466a04>,
 {12: {'charcount': 25, 'longword': 1},
  13: {'charcount': 38, 'longword': 1}})
```

---

Another solution using `collectons.Counter` and `collections.defaultdict`:

```
import sys
import ast
from collections import defaultdict, Counter
keys = ['longword', 'charcount']
my_dict = defaultdict(Counter)
for line in sys.stdin:
    d = ast.literal_eval(line)
    key = list(d)[0]
    my_dict[key].update(**{k:d[key][k] for k in keys})
print my_dict
```

**Output:**

```
defaultdict(<class 'collections.Counter'>,
{12: Counter({'charcount': 25, 'longword': 1}),
 13: Counter({'charcount': 38, 'longword': 1})})
```

Answer (score 1):

something straightforward as

```
from collections import defaultdict

dicts =[ { 12: {'@': False, '#': False, 'word': 'good#1st#time#will',    'longword': True, 'title': False, 'charcount': 18, 'uppercase': False, 'stop': False, 'sscore': False, 'url': False, '!!!': False} },
     { 12: {'@': False, '#': False, 'word': 'be', 'longword': False, 'title': False,   'charcount': 2, 'uppercase': False, 'stop': True, 'sscore': False, 'url': False, '!!!': False} },
     { 13: {'@': False, '#': False, 'word': 'back#', 'longword': False, 'title': False, 'charcount': 5, 'uppercase': False, 'stop': False, 'sscore': False, 'url': False, '!!!': False} },
     { 13: {'@': False, '#': False, 'word': 'http://instagr.am/p/rx9939civ8/\xc2\xa0', 'longword': True, 'title': False, 'charcount': 33, 'uppercase': False, 'stop': False, 'sscore': False, 'url': True, '!!!': False} },
     { 12: {'@': False, '#': False, 'word': 'going', 'longword': False, 'title': False, 'charcount': 5, 'uppercase': False, 'stop': False, 'sscore': False, 'url': False, '!!!': False} }
]

result = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))

for d in dicts:
    for k, v in d.items():
        result[k]['longword'] += v.get('longword', 0)
        result[k]['charcount'] += v.get('charcount', 0)

for k, v in result.items():
    print k, dict(v)
#12 {'charcount': 25, 'longword': 1}
#13 {'charcount': 38, 'longword': 1}
```